# Covariance changes on each run

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis

Is it normal that every time I run the following code, I get different covariance?

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
from pylab import *

def de_mean(x):
    xmean = mean(x)
    return [xi - xmean for xi in x]


def covariance(x, y):
    n = len(x)
    return dot(de_mean(x), de_mean(y)) / (n-1)

pageSpeeds = np.random.normal(3.0, 1.0, 1000)
purchaseAmount = np.random.normal(50.0, 10.0, 1000)

scatter(pageSpeeds, purchaseAmount)

covariance (pageSpeeds, purchaseAmount)
```

Answer (score 1):

That makes perfect sense: you are finding the covariance of random data.  You get different random numbers on each run.  if you want reproducible results, then set the random-number generator to a constant value before you build your arrays.  For instance, insert this line at the top of your main program:

```
numpy.random.seed(0)
```